# Having trouble adjusting to new manager's communication style. Thinking of quitting

Tags: communication, management, new-hires

I have been working a part time job for several years. From the feedback I have been getting, I have been doing it well. Recently I got a new manager. The former manager was really great. I found that my communication style and work style went well with her's. I have had difficulty with the new manager, more so for several small reasons rather than one main one. I think the new manager reports to the former manager. The former one told me the new one is still in training and I can reach out to her for help. I was introduce to the new manager by the former one in an email. In it, the former manager said I would continue to get the same number of shifts. This hasn't been happening. I tried speaking to the new manager but he just said he would get back to me and didn't (as he often does). So I replied all to the email pointing out that I hadn't been getting shifts. The former manager came up with a schedule for me but said the new manager will be entering it into the official scheduling system (which he still hasn't). I had understood that the former manager told the new one that I am good at my job and can be left alone to do it independently.

Today the new manager told me I was doing a good job. Then he said some vagugue life advice like "nothing in this world is certain" and "in life ask when you want something, but only ask once". By the change in his tone and body language it sounded like something was wrong. I asked him why he was telling me to only ask for things once. He gave me a serious look and said "I think you know why". There was some back and forth but I think the main point was he didn't like that I asked twice to get more shifts and that I had involved the former manager.

Any advice on how to deal with this? I repeat things because he doesn't answer (or gives a very unclear answer like when I ask "should I do x or will someone else be doing it?" he replies "x will be done"). What else can I do? I'm thinking of quitting. Should I try asking for a new manager? If I do quit should I bother doing the newly assigned shifts? Whenever I contact the former manager, I tell her that I've already tried talking to the new manager. Should I be doing that?

TL;DR new manager doesn't like that I repeat myself. I do this because he doesn't answer (clearly) in the first place.

Comment: Have you spoken about this with your nre manager at all?

Comment: That "Whenever I contact the former manager" in the penultimate paragraph suggests an alternative TL;DR : "I keep going over my manager's head. Any ideas why the relationship isn't working?"

Comment: "**when I ask "should I do x or will someone else be doing it?" he replies "x will be done")**" -- He leaves it up to you and your coworkers. In his mind, there are 3 scenarios as follows. (1) If you are not busy and you want to take on x, then you can work on x. (2) If you are busy with other tasks, then someone else will work on x. (3) If you are NOT busy and you don't want to work on x, then someone else will work on x, and you can choose to work on something else.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul yes I have. The result is usually not constructive.

Comment: Sounds like the new manager doesn't like you very much and is clearly exercising the only power he has over you...the ability to not put you on the schedule until you up and quit. Second paragraph is a huge signal which you shouldn't simply ignore. Don't tell your old manager anything about the new manager as managers are usually buddy-buddy and people talk. Asking for a new manager isn't going to help. It'll only make matters worse for you. Unfortunately, the workforce just doesn't work that way and you don't get to choose the manager. 

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have decided to quit. I would really like to provide the constructive feedback that the main reason I'm quitting is because I find the new managers communication style makes it difficult or impossible to do my job. Wouldn't this be the honest thing to do? Should I provide copies where he is unable to give a clear answer to things like "am I working tomorrow?". I feel bad that the previous manager tried to help with the transition but it was still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I repeat things because he doesn't answer...

Have you actually told him this?

And do you have a reasonable justification for asking the question, and expecting an answer?

It certainly seems legitimate to ask whether you need to do a task or whether someone else will do it, so if your manager replies to your question "task X will be done", it would be perfectly appropriate to follow up "Yes, but by whom do you want it to be done? Me, or another colleague?".

Consider whether it may also be appropriate to suggest an answer (especially to a new manager who might not have a full grasp of everything yet), to liaise directly with the other person who might potentially do the task, or to suggest a system by which the decision should be made routinely.

If you are considering leaving anyway, it might also be appropriate to change the tone of the interaction over shift planning, and explain that you're not asking for more shifts, but requiring that the established volume is maintained.

It might be appropriate to attempt to start a conversation about why the volumes, or the distribution of available shifts, has changed.

Comment: Good points! "Have you actually told him this?" no, the argument/conversation was dragging on and I did not think of this until after the fact. I find I have a tendency of thinking of things I wish I had said after the conversation had ended.

Comment: @myusernameis123, indeed, to some extent you wonder how certain people ever become managers when they themselves lack communication and organisation skills - I think perhaps it's because people are promoted for being effective subordinates to a higher manager, rather than because they display management qualities themselves. But even if the time has passed, there is nothing wrong with you restarting a conversation about unresolved questions you still need answers to.

Comment: "I think perhaps it's because people are promoted for being effective subordinates to a higher manage" the reason for this change was because my manager was promoted internally and her replacement was hired externally. When I asked what I could do to get promoted or a raise I was told there was no chance because my position was part time. Even though I appreciate the direct answer, I found this to be very demoralizing. Especially when I see a lot of other people working for the company not taking their job seriously and cutting corners. It's this sense of unfairness that is making me unhappy.

Comment: @myusernameis123, yes, so effectively the situation is that you were being managed by a manager suitable for a higher grade, and you would be suitable for management yourself, and between the pair of you is now a second-rate manager hired externally. Your company's issue with part-time managers may simply be that it implies other responsibilities that compete for your time and attention. It may also be that managers impose organisational overheads roughly in proportion to their number, not their working hours, so a part-time manager imposes a full overhead for half capacity. (1/2)

Comment: Finally, it may not be seen as possible for a part-time manager to properly be able to supervise full-timers, or for their part-time hours to align with enough other part-time staff. (2/2)

Comment: How would you phrase it, that I have to repeat myself because he doesn't answer? How would you start the conversation? Something like "I know you told me not to repeat myself but I don't know what else to do when you don't answer. For example I'm still wondering about xyz".

Comment: @myusernameis123, well I would suggest remaining sensitive to potential reasons why the answers aren't forthcoming. In the absence of any clear idea what the problem is, so as to tailor the question, I might try something like "Bob, have you come to a decision yet on X? I could do with knowing by tomorrow because Y, and the old manager usually has to make this decision because Z."

Comment: Just wondering, when I ask "what do you mean that I repeat myself" and the manager says "I think you know", is that a sign of a more deeply rooted communication issue? I actually can only think of two times I've had to repeat myself.

Comment: @myusernameis123, well in your question you suggest you're having to repeat yourself all the time because your manager never answers - that's hardly consistent with saying you've asked a repeat question only twice. The manager was obviously expressing annoyance, most likely at a specific question/issue. You yourself acknowledge that the shifts/working hours issue, which you've escalated to your old manager, is the most likely issue.

Comment: This is what I mean I have trouble communicating with him. When he phrased it "in life, don't repeat yourself" it sounded like a pervasive issue, but when I asked him what he meant he just gave the one example (but i could think of one or two other times I had to ask him to clarify).

Comment: @myusernameis123, it's impossible to say at a distance what caused your manager to say those exact words. Maybe it was just an unfortunate turn of phrase, intended to be airy and gently non-specific about a very specific instance, rather than intended to be philosophically grave and of general importance. The most appropriate person to have a conversation with, is the person whose words you're struggling to interpret.